# Why when uploading a video file to youtube it's uploading it to my second gmail account?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube

On my desktop pc i have one gmail account.
On my laptop here i have another differenet gmail account.

My JSON file: client_secrets contain on both laptop and desktop pc same one gmail account the one on my desktop pc. But when i'm uploading the video file from my laptop it's uploading it to my gmail account on the laptop. And i want it to upload it to my gmail youtube account on my desktop pc.

First why on the laptopn it's uploading to the gmail account on the laptop and not the gmail on the desktop pc ? 
Second how can i change it ? Even if on laptop and desktop pc i'm using same client_secrets file on laptopn it's uploading it to the gmail on the laptop.

another thing is that on my laptop i'm connected to my gmail account of the laptop and on the desktop pc connected to the gmail account of the desktop pc.
But i was sure that the gmail account on the JSON file set where the file will be upload to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace Youtubeupload
{
    public partial class Youtube_Uploader : Form
    {
        public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

        YouTubeService service;

        string apiKey = "myapikey";
        string FileNameToUpload = "";
        string[] stringProgressReport = new string[5];
        long totalBytes = 0;
        DateTime dt;
        public static string fileuploadedsuccess = "";
        Upload upload;

        public Youtube_Uploader(string filetoupload)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileNameToUpload = @"C:\Users\tester\Videos\test.mp4";
            service = AuthenticateOauth(apiKey);
            var videoCatagories = service.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
            videoCatagories.RegionCode = "IL";
            var result = videoCatagories.Execute();
            MakeRequest();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public static string uploadstatus = "";
        Video objects = null;
        private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
            aTimer.Interval = 10000;
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            if (uploadstatus == "uploaded")
            {
                fileuploadedsuccess = "file uploaded successfully";
            }
            if (uploadstatus == "Completed")
            {
                fileuploadedsuccess = "completed";
            }
            objects = obj;
        }

        void aTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        double mbSent = 0;
        int percentComplete = 0;
        VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress vp = new VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress();
        private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {            
            ulong? ul = vp.TimeLeftMs;
            stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
            mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
            stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString();
            percentComplete = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
            stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();

            if (obj.BytesSent != 0)
            {
                var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan diff = currentTime - dt;
                double diffSeconds = (DateTime.Now - dt).TotalSeconds;
                double averageSpeed = obj.BytesSent / diffSeconds;
                double MBunits = ConvertBytesToMegabytes((long)averageSpeed);
                stringProgressReport[4] = string.Format("{0:f2} MB/s", MBunits);
            }
        }

        public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string apiKey)
        {
            try
            {
                YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = apiKey,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Uploader",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void MakeRequest()
        {
            var searchListRequest = service.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "daniel lipman gta"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.RegionCode = "IL";
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

            List<string> videos = new List<string>();
            List<string> channels = new List<string>();
            List<string> playlists = new List<string>();
            // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
                {
                    case "youtube#video":
                        videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#channel":
                        channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#playlist":
                        playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static Video video = new Video();
        private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\C-Sharp\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\Youtube-Manager\bin\Debug\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
                }
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
                });

                video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
                video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
                video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
                video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
                video.Status = new VideoStatus();
                video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {

                    const int KB = 0x400;
                    var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                    // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
                    videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
                    dt = DateTime.Now;
                    videosInsertRequest.Upload();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                string errorss = errors.ToString();
            }
        }

        static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
        {
            return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
        }

        private void Youtube_Uploader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            UploadVideo(FileNameToUpload, "Gta v ps4", "Testing gta v ps4");
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int eventIndex = 0;
            try
            {
                eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.UserState == null ? "null" : e.UserState.GetType().FullName);
                throw;
            }

            if (eventIndex == 0) // upload status.
            {
                label14.Text = stringProgressReport[0];
            }
            else if (eventIndex == 1) // obj.Status
            {
                label16.Text = stringProgressReport[1];
            }
            else if (eventIndex == 2) // mb sent so far
            {
                stringProgressReport[2];
                label5.Text = stringProgressReport[2];
            }
            else if (eventIndex == 3) // percent complete
            {
                progressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[3]);
            }
            else if (eventIndex == 4) // percent complete
            {
                label8.Text = stringProgressReport[4];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid event index: " + eventIndex);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What i want is that it will upload the video files to my gmail account that is on the desktop pc even if i'm uploading it from the laptop pc and there i'm connected to another gmail account.

Comment: What i mean is to be able to upload the video file to another user channel. For example in my laptopn i'm connected to my gmail test@gmail.com but on my desktop i'm connected to ddd@gmail.com i want to upload the video file on the laptop to ddd@gmail.com but what i'm doing it's uploading it to the test@gmail.com

Comment: In other words i want to upload in my laptop to my channel on the desktop gmail. But it keep uploading to the gmail channel account on the laptop. And i don't want to disconnect from ym laptop gmail account to connect to the gmail account that i use on my desktop. I want to be connected on my laptop with my laptop gmail account and yet to upload to the account that i use on my desktop.